# "No rule to make target" Error When Using make -j with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

When I use "make -j" I get a "No rule to make target" error.  When I use make (no -j), I don't get the error.  The library is built as follows in one directory:

```
add_library(Environment ${CXXSRCS}
```

and libEnvironment.a is created.  In another directory libEnvironment.a is referenced:

```
add_executable(GetEnv ${GETSRCS})
target_link_libraries(GetEnv
    ${tools_environment_SOURCE_DIR}/libEnvironment.a
    xml++-2.6
    )
```

When I run with "cmake -j",  I get the error then the library gets created, but cmake stops.  When I run cmake -j again, everything is happy because the library has been created.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `make -j` is in use, any targets may be built in parallel unless one target is **explicitely** set as depended from another.

In you case you have `GetEnv` (executable) target which uses files, produced by `Environment` (library) target. But you have no explicit dependencies between targets!

Correct (and the simplest) way for link with libraries is using library target name instead of library file, which is created by that target:

> target_link_libraries(GetEnv **Environment** xml++-2.6)

Such a way you will have dependency between `GetEnv` and `Environment` targets, so `make -j` will no longer attempt to build them in parallel.

Comment: That worked!  I'd give you an uptick but I don't have the street cred.

Comment: @DougFulford Accept the answer, then we know this question is answered. Thanks.