# 'make -j4' failing but 'make' passing on new build machine

Tags: makefile, build, cmake, gnu-make, azure-pipelines

Trying to move over a VSTS build agent to a new VM. On the old machine the command `make -j4` ran with no problem, but on the new VM it fails with: `*** No rule to make target ___ Stop.` When I run a regular `make` command on this new machine it works no problem. What do I need to change or upgrade on the new machine to make it work with `make -j4` ?

Comment: The most likely is that your Makefile is not parallel safe. Some dependencies are not properly declared. It was working in your old environment by chance. If you do not show your Makefile we cannot help you finding why.

Comment: This is a CMake based build. The makefile is autogenerated by running `cmake CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: This person had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802800/no-rule-to-make-target-error-when-using-make-j-with-cmake Maybe you should post CMakeLists.txt?